# Xcode Camera: Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary revisited

Tags: ios, swift

This question has been asked before but the answers (particularly the most upvoted answer) does not solve the problem.  Using Xcode 12.5 when I use the camera I get an error message:

[Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error    Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}

The suggested answer is in part:

"If you instead use imagePicker.allowsEditing = false, use this to pick image:

```
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        capturedImage = pickedImage        
    }
```

So far as I can see, this is exactly the same as my code which sets

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
```

and then:

```
    if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        defaultImage = userPickedImage
    }
```

The error seems to be harmless but it is driving me nuts.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Comment: "The error seems to be harmless but it is driving me nuts. Any suggestions?" File a bug report to Apple and chill?